# Add column to data frame with loop calculation from another data frame

Tags: r, for-loop, data-manipulation, data-management

I have two datasets, one at the individual level and one at the school level. I would like to calculate the proportion of fighting in each school using a loop (since i have >100 schools).

Current code:

```
for (i in levels(df$school_id)) {
     school <- subset(df, school_id == i)
     number_students <- nrow(school)
     prop <- (sum(school$fight_binary, na.rm = TRUE))/number_students
     df$proportion_fight[df$school_id == i] <- prop
}
```

I tried initializing the new column first, but when I run this loop nothing happens at all.

Here's some sample data

INDIVIDUAL LEVEL:

```
student_id   school_id   ever_fight
         1           2            1
         2           3            0
         3           1            1
         4           1            1
         5           2            0
         6           2            0
         7           2            0
         8           2            0
         9           3            1
        10           1            0
        11           3            1
        12           3            1
        13           3            1
        14           3            1
        15           1            0
        16           2            0
        17           1            0
        18           1            0
        19           1            0
        20           1            0
```

SCHOOL LEVEL (need to fill the second column with data from above):

```
 school_id    proportion_fight
         1
         2
         3
```

Comment: I think you need `library(dplyr); df1 %>% group_by(school_id) %>% summarise(proportion = mean(ever_flight))`

Comment: Yes that worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

We can use a group by `mean`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
     group_by(school_id) %>% 
     summarise(proportion_flight = mean(ever_flight))
```